# On keypress zoom my Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a various images displayed one below the other at the center of the page.
On keyPress I want to display or zoom a particular image in the list at the center of the page.

Something like, the image is not zoomed, but another copy of the image from that position is displayed using transition.

The code I have tried is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="channel.change.css" />
 <script>
    var image = document.getElementById("img1");
image.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

    function doKeyDown(e){

        //====================
        //  THE W KEY
        //====================
        if (e.keyCode == 87) {
                            image.setAttribute('style', 'width:300px !important;');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<img id="img1" src="http://sphotos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-   snc6/189287_403070459759757_137788631_n.png" alt="" class="zoom_image"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code is :

```
.zoom_image
{
display: block;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:80px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
}

.zoom_image:hover
{
width:500px;
height:480px;
left:-25px;
top:-25px;
z-index:9999;
}
```

I want my css to apply on the image on keyPress

Comment: You should be able to zoom the same image. Read up on [CSS3 transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) `scale`

Comment: I am able to zoom, but that on muse hover. But key press is not working. Also how to replace ` image.setAttribute('style', 'width:300px !important;');` with the css stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);` instead

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/DfH4e/1/)

W to zoom-in, X to zoom-out

(this will only work in chrome though, for other browsers you'll have to add browser-specific css)

Comment: It's working for me(on chrome). Select the view section in the fiddle and press `W`, it will scale up

Comment: Its working on fiddle, but when i run from notepad++..it doesn't

Comment: Try putting your `script` tag at the end(just before the `</body>`). Your script isn't waiting for the document to load